# Designing a PHP API wrapper

Tags: php, frameworks, wrapper

I was wondering what is a good method to implement two similair API's into one PHP framework?

My thought was something like this:

- /vendors/wrapperA.php -  extends Parent, implements API **(A)**
- /vendors/wrapperB.php - extends Parent, implements API **(B)**
- Parent.php - **the only script referenced directly** to use the API wrapper
- $config[] array for configuration in Parent.php
- index.php - A website that implements and **only references Parent.php**

Let's say the API's have many methods, but we only implement two simple API calls:

- connect() - creates a connection to the service.
- put() - returns a "putID" if successful.

Since API **(A)** and API **(B)** differ, this is how the wrapper implements its utility, by abstracting these two methods.

Now, to my point:

- What would be a good way to implement this in PHP?
- the connect() statement would need to validate there is a valid connection.
- the put() statement would need to return an ID
- we don't want to expose the differences in the put methods, it just needs to work based on if we configured our API authentication correctly (whatever the case may be - via secret key or otherwise)

i.e.

Something like

```
<?php $parent = new Parent();
$parent->connect(); //connect to one or both API's.
$parent->put('foo'); //push foo to the API
?>
```

Currently, I have all of my code in Parent.php.

Issues with having all of the code in Parent.php

1. Code sprawl
2. Lack of modular plugins in case I add a 3rd API.
3. Code confusion - which API is which?

**EDIT: Solution devised based on Marin's answer**

```
<?php 

/*** Interface ***/

interface API_Wrapper {
    function connect();
    function put($file);
} 

/*** API Wrappers ***/
class API_A_Wrapper implements API_Wrapper {
    function connect() {}
    function put($file) { print 'putting to API A.'; }
}

class API_B_Wrapper implements API_Wrapper {
    function connect() {}
    function put($file) { print 'putting to API B.'; }
}

/*** Factory ***/
class Factory {
  public static function create($type){ 
    switch ($type) {
      case "API_A" : 
        $obj = new API_A_Wrapper(); 
      break;
      case "API_B" :
        $obj = new API_B_Wrapper();  
      break;
    }
    return $obj;
   } 

} 

/*** Usage ***/

$wrapperA = Factory::create("API_A");
$wrapperA->put('foo');

$wrapperB = Factory::create("API_B");
$wrapperB->put('foo');
```

Comment: IMHO. `Parent` should just be an interface, at most a Factory that creates WrapperA or WrapperB objects... This way, you always know which class you have, and the interface stays the same. If you _need_ just one class for some reason, go for a Decorator pattern.

Comment: How does an interface prevent code sprawl? I currently put my code in Parent.php. As I add more methods, I'm using a $this->framework variable, and this will not not be extensible for very long.

Comment: From what I understand, you are trying to have a single API to drive several others, ie. one API which maps to the use of several other API at once. Is that correct?

Comment: Not by its nature, no. An Interface would help when needing a 3rd API that might be wildly different. If WrapperA & WrapperB are much alike, it's possible they inherit from the same abstract class, which could implement the interface. To be honest, I was more focused on 2 & 3, and the fact that `Parent` was apparently called directly ;)

Comment: @didierc I should clarify - more of a framework wrapping two API's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface with relation and call it separately when you need it:

```
interface Interface {
    function somefunction();
}

class Wrapper1 implements Relation {
    public function connect() {
        return;
    }
}

class Wrapper2 {
    public function action(Interface $s) {
        $textData = $s->query();
        return;
    }
}

$p = new Wrapper1();

$i = new Wrapper2();
$i->action($p);
```

Using factory as relation:

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    include_once($class . '.php');
}

class DBfactory
{
    public static $pDB;

    public static function factory($szType = "")
    {
    if(!is_object(self::$pDB))
    {
        switch($szType)
        {
            case 'mysql':
                self::$pDB = new DBmysql;
                break;
            case 'mssql':
                self::$pDB = new DBmssql;
                break;
            default:
                self::$pDB = new DBmysql;
                break;
        }
    }
    return self::$pDB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Marin. Thanks for responding. Both API's require authentication, so I would need a connect() method in both. I don't quite follow your basic example. It looks like your wrapper2 implements functionality from wrapper1, but that is not the case in my situation. Both API's are vastly different.

Comment: You need use factory pattern inside of class for shared using class. Put function inside `Wrapper` and call factory pattern for shared class. Look at this example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536507/creating-an-interface-in-php-which-can-specify-a-type-to-determine-which-class

Comment: Thanks, Marin. I've updated my question with a solution using this method.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is denpendency injection. You have 2 classes - you call them wrappers - which each covers a different API, but must conform to the same interface. In your web site, you wish to use either classes interchangeably, in effect using any underlying API without impacting the rest of the codebase, hence the common `Parent` interface.

However, at some point, your code will have to decide which wrapper will be used, and if you want to include new `Parent` implementations, you are afraid of having to manually include these new wrappers in your code base.

This problem is solved by dependency injection. The idea is to have a dedicated object - a Factory - encapsulate all the details of which wrappers are available, and any bit of code which require the wrapper of the moment may ask it to that factory. Clearly, your code will only have to deal with the factory and instance of the `Parent` interface.

For as to how the Factory decides which wrapper to instantiate is your choice to make. Many use a configuration file containing which class must be used with which part of the code. That can be implemented by using ids associated with wrapper clients (ie code using them)  and clients would give the factory this id when requesting the wrapper. The factory then just look the id up and provide an ad-hoc instance.